# Why the output return NaN when I want to translate certain language (Malay) to English in Python?

Tags: python, google-translation-api

Firstly, I use FasText for language detection. Then, from the language detection, I want to translate from certain language (in this case, Malay) to English. For the translation part, I use Google Translate API using Python. The problem is, the output return NaN value for other language (in this case, English and Thai). I want to return only the translated text only, which is Malay.

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
translator = Translator()


df = pd.DataFrame({
'text': ["how are you", "suka makan nasi ayam", "สวัสด","hai, apa khabar"], 
'lang': ["english", "malay", "thai","malay"]
})
df
```

**Dataframe df:**

[image]

```
df1=df[df["lang"] == "malay"]
df['text'] = df1['text'].apply(translator.translate, dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
df
```

**Generated output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

```
text                       |    lang
-----------------------------------
how are you                |   english
like to eat chicken rice   |   malay
สวัสด                      |   thai
Hello how are you          |   malay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a boolean mask:

```
translate_en = lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text

m = df['lang'] == 'malay'
df.loc[m, 'text'] = df.loc[m, 'text'].apply(translate_en)
print(df)

# Output
                       text     lang
0               how are you  english
1  like to eat chicken rice    malay
2                     สวัสด     thai
3         Hello how are you    malay
```

Same with `update`:

```
df.update(df.loc[m, 'text'].apply(translate_en))
print(df)

# Output
                       text     lang
0               how are you  english
1  like to eat chicken rice    malay
2                     สวัสด     thai
3         Hello how are you    malay
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. If I want to add additional condition, is it possible to use boolean mask?

Comment: Totally. The boolean mask is here to hide rows. You can add some conditions. Like `m = (df['lang'] == 'malay') | (df['lang'] == 'thai')`